# Terminology: lifting a probability distribution along a function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, terminology

We write $\mathbb{D}(A)$ for the set of all discrete  probability distributions over $A$, in other words, all functions $d : A \rightarrow [0, 1]$ that sum up to 1, i.e. $\Sigma_{a \in A}d(a) = 1$. (Note the question can easily be generalised to arbitrary probability distributions.)

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function. We now 'lift' probability distributions from $A$ to $B$ using $f$ as follows: each $\mathbb{P} \in \mathbb{D}(A)$ is mapped to the function $\mathsf{lift}(\mathbb{P})$, given as:
$$
    b \quad\mapsto\quad \Sigma\{\mathbb{P}(a) \ |\ a \in A, f(a) = b\}
$$

in $\mathbb{D}(B)$. In other words,  $\mathsf{lift}$ is an element of the function space
$
   \mathsf{lift} : \mathbb{D}(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{D}(B)
$. Or, written more succinctly, $b$ maps to $\Sigma\mathbb{P}[f^{-1}(b)]$. This, surely, is a widely used construction.

**Question.** What is this 'lifting' construction called in probability theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a random variable on the probability space $(A, 2^A, \mathbb P)$, and the distribution $\mathbb P f^{-1}$ is its pushforward measure. (In general, for $f$ to be a random variable, it must be measurable, but for the discrete $\sigma$-algebra this is trivial.)

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful, this helps me a great deal, as googling *"pushforward measure"* gives me a lot of relevant pointers, in particular, a relationship with the Giry Monad (aka probability monad). I had a feeling that a lot of my constructions have been monadic. (I'm not a mathematician)